# Batch Script to copy files from a Text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need help with below code as it is executing in root folder only whereas I want the code to look for files within sub folders as well.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (documents.txt) do (
   copy %%A E:\Destination\ 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use this command line in the batch file to copy all files with duplicating directory structure from source to destination directory.

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in (documentation.txt) do %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%~dp0." "E:\Destination" "%%~I" /S /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS
```

It is assumed that the file `documentation.txt` contains a list of file names without path.

The command **FOR** reads one line after the other from file `documentation.txt` with skipping empty lines. The end of line character is modified from default `;` to `|` using option `eol=|` to be able copying also files of which name starts unusually with a semicolon. No file name can contain a vertical bar anywhere. The line splitting behavior on spaces/tabs is disabled by using option `delims=` which defines in this case an empty list of string delimiters. Therefore file names with one or more space even at beginning of file name read from file are assigned unmodified to loop variable `I`. The option `tokens=*` removes leading spaces/tabs from the lines read from text file. A file name can begin with one or more spaces although such file names are unusual.

**FOR** runs for each file name the executable **ROBOCOPY** with directory of the batch file as source folder path and `E:\Destination` as destination folder path. **ROBOCOPY** interprets a `\` left of one more `\` or `"` as escape character. For that reason the source and destination folder paths should never end with a backslash as this would result in `"` being interpreted not as end of folder path, but everything up to next `"` in command line. For that reason `.` is appended to `%~dp0` because of `%~dp0` always expands to batch file folder path ending with a backslash. The dot at end of batch file folder path references the current folder of batch file folder. In other words with batch file stored in `C:\Temp` the batch file folder can be referenced with `C:\Temp\` as done with `%~dp0` but not possible with **ROBOCOPY** or with `C:\Temp\.` as done with `%~dp0.` or with just `C:\Temp` or with `C:\Temp\\` as done with `%~dp0\` which would also work with **ROBOCOPY**. See the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) for details.

Remove `%~dp0` to use current folder as source folder instead of batch file folder.

The **ROBOCOPY** option `/S` results in searching in source folder and all its subfolders for the file and copy each found file to destination folder with duplicating the source folder structure in destination folder.

The other **ROBOCOPY** options are just for **not** printing list of created directories, list of copied files, header and summary.

---

Here is an alternative command line for this task copying all files from source directory tree into destination directory without creating subdirectories. So all copied files are finally in specified destination directory.

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in (documentation.txt) do for /F "delims=" %%J in ('dir "%~dp0%%~I" /A-D-H /B /S 2^>nul') do copy /B /Y "%%J" "E:\Destination\" >nul
```

The inner **FOR** starts for each file name assigned to loop variable `I` of outer **FOR** one more command process in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the **DIR** command line appended as additional arguments. So executed is for each file name in `documentation.txt` with Windows installed into `C:\Windows` for example:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir "C:\Batch File Path\Current File Name.ext" /A-D-H /B /S 2>nul
```

The command **DIR** executed by second `cmd.exe` in background searches

- in directory of the batch file
- and all its subdirectories because of option `/S`
- only for non-hidden files because of option `/A-D-H` (attribute not directory and not hidden)
- with the specified file name
- and outputs in bare format because of option `/B`
- just the names of the found files with full path because of option `/S`.

It is possible that **DIR** cannot find a file matching these criteria at all in which case it would output an error message to handle **STDERR** of the background command process. This error message is suppressed by redirecting it with `2>nul` to device **NUL**.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The inner **FOR** captures everything written to handle **STDOUT** of started background command process and processes this output line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself after finishing execution of **DIR**.

The inner **FOR** assigns each full qualified file name to specified loop variable `J` without any modification because of option `delims=` and runs next the command **COPY** to copy that file as binary file to destination directory with automatically overwriting an existing file in destination directory with same file name. The success message output by **COPY** to handle **STDOUT** is redirected with `>nul` to device **NUL** to suppress it. An error message would be output by **COPY**. An error occurs if destination directory does not exist, or the destination directory is write-protected, or an existing file with same name is write-protected due to a read-only attribute or file permissions, or source file is opened by an application with sharing read access denied, or an existing destination file is opened by an application with sharing write access denied.

---

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... for an explanation of `%~dp0` referencing drive and path of argument 0 which is the full qualified path of the batch file currently processed by `cmd.exe`.
- `copy /?`
- `dir /?`
- `for /?`
- `robocopy /?`